# How to convert a Firefox epoch to a human-readable date

Tags: linux, firefox

Firefox tables often contain the column dateAdded for dates in which events occurred in terms of Unix epoch in milliseconds. One such example I had recently was 1673106294677000. I removed the three last 0s to convert to seconds and ran the following script:

```
charlie@kali:~$ date -d @1673106294677
Sun 17 Aug 05:31:17 BST 54988
```

As you can see, the date is not accurate, it should be some time in the last month or so, not a date thousands of years in the future!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sure that's milliseconds?

Comment: that value is in microseconds

Comment: @MarcusMüller - no, it's microseconds as _Jaromanda X_ said. It's the [PRTime](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/nspr/reference/prtime.html)

Comment: microseconds translate to GMT Saturday, January 7, 2023 3:44:54.677 PM

Comment: Which means to use `date -d @$((1673106294677/1000))`.